# Why only the first of 2 widgets receive my stream?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an EventChannel that receives messages from Kotlin:

```
final stream = const EventChannel('com.my_app.event_channel');

widget.stream.receiveBroadcastStream("hello").listen((event) {
```

the problem is that if I have 2 instances of this same widget, only the first one will receive the stream, the other not.

How do I make it such that both receive the stream?

By the way, what does the `hello` mean? It doesn't change anything, but I get an error if I don't put anything

Comment: you need `hello` and `hello2` then

Comment: @pskink it still receives only on one widget